# Unable to convert numpy array into a tensor for model.fit

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am a beginner to ML and I am having trouble converting a numpy array into a tensor when fitting the model.

The error I get when I try

```
    test_audio_class(x_train.values, y_train.values, x_test.values, y_test.values)
```

is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier.py", line 51, in <module>
    test_audio_class(x_train.values, y_train.values, x_test.values, y_test.values)
  File "classifier.py", line 28, in test_audio_class
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data = (x_test, y_test))

line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor).
```

I tried some print statements to figure out the error.

```
type of x_train = <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, values in x_train = <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
type of y_train = <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, values in y_train = <class 'str'>
```

I know it has something to do with the `EagerTensor` that I am doing but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Why is your dataset made of EagerTensor? You should include the code that produces the data.

Answer (score 0):

model.fit expects input data could be:

- A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model
  has multiple inputs).
- A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in
  case the model has multiple inputs).
- A dict mapping input names to
  the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs.

Please refer to the following code snippet on your inputs which will solve your problem.

```
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)
```

Alternatively, you can as well do this :

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Do leave a comment in case a further intervention is required.